# Getting the window size of the opener window (IE)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

For FF and other non-IE browsers, window.opener.outerWidth/Height give me the info I need. For IE, I'm still at a loss, from IE6 to 8. I can't use jquery as the opener's page is beyond my control, so I can't do a window.opener.$(window). This requires the opener to have jquery 'attached' (correct me if I'm wrong).

I googled quite a bit and also searched this site, still can't find a definite neat answer.

To add:
I really need the outer size so that I can do a resizeTo(w, h) for the opened window where w and h are calculated based on a ratio of the opener's size. "resizeTo" ironically sets the outer size for IE and other browsers. I also tried a messy loads of stuff using resizeBy, not good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`outerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.outerWidth) and `outerHeight` define dimensions of the browser window (including sidebar, window chrome and window [re-]sizing borders/handles). Unfortunately you cannot get these dimensions in IE - only the window viewport dimensions are available (good enough for most applications I've seen). Aka [`window.innerWidth`/`window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.innerWidth).

jQuery can give you the dimensions of the current window viewport, but not other windows (eg, openers, children, etc). So you'll have to code this yourself. Here is a crude sample:

```
// get viewport size (without scrolling) of the given window object
function clientSize(win) {
    var width, height;

    if(win.innerWidth || win.innerHeight) {
        width = win.innerWidth;
        height = win.innerHeight;
    } else {
        var doc = win.document;
        width = doc.documentElement.clientWidth || doc.body.clientWidth;
        height = doc.documentElement.clientHeight || doc.body.clientHeight;
    }

    return { width:width, height:height }
}
```

Try it like:

```
var openerSize = clientSize(window.opener); 
// now use openerSize.width, openerSize.height
```

Also note that you can't read any of these values if the given window has loaded a document from another domain (security measure).

Comment: @crescentfresh Thanks for the answer. I've actually tried using the method you mentioned before I posted this question. The issue is, I really need the outer size so that I can do a resizeTo(w, h) for the opened window where w and h are calculated based on a ratio or the opener's size. "resizeTo" ironically sets the outer size for IE and other browsers. I also tried a messy loads of stuff using resizeBy, not good enough. Anyway +1 for your inputs :)

Comment: @o.k.w: if your end goal is to call `resizeTo()`, you can do the trick  here: http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/1178 All it does is issue a throwaway fixed sized call to `resizeTo(500, 500)`, subtract the values IE reports, and use those in the *real* `resizeTo` call later.

Comment: @crescentfresh My end goal is to have the new window resized to a fixed ratio of the opener. So resizeTo is the most straightforward. ResizeBy was a side trip I tried. Your suggestion will work though kinda unorthodox, yeah? Anyway, appreciate it and if no better solution comes along, I might just do that. :-)

Comment: @o.k.w: yeah it's very unorthodox. The reason it may be an acceptable solution is because you're going to be doing a `resizeTo()` *anyway*. Otherwise, you'd be sizing the window for no apparent usefulness to the user experience.